# Como pasar variables a esta funcion y extraer datos de una funcion? Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

Tengo una pequeña consulta , estoy usando SignalR con C# y Javascript , pero tengo un problema tengo unas variables fuera de la funcion, quisiera como saber que las variables ingresen a la funcion, o necesito ponerla en la funcion de SignalR y luego retonarla?

Luego si quiero recuperar lo que me devuelva esa funcion por ejemplo un string para usarla fuera de esa funcion, como podria hacerlo?

La funcion en c# :

```
public string FuncionCualquiera(string GroupName,string UserId)
    {
        var id = Context.ConnectionId;
        Clients.Group(GroupName).ReceiveTypingRequest(id);

        return UserId;
    }
```

al hacer seguimiento , me devuelve un string correctamente.

Javascript
Aqui es la funcion del que les habló, necesito extraer string y enviar variables , pero no sé como lograrlo.
Gracias.
[image: Funcion Javacript]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debido a que la ejecucion del metodeo `.done()` es asíncrono, no puedes obtener el resultado utilizando un `return`.

Para lograr lo que quieres utiliza un callback que es una funcion que se ejecutara cuando se ejecute el metodo `.done()` y asi podras obtener el valor de la variable:

```js
// defines la funcion que recibira el valor del metodo done
var respuesta = function(ruta){
  alert(ruta); // haces lo que tengas que hacer con la ruta
};

chatHub.server.sendGroupMessage(ChatId,MessageId,UserId).done(function(Ruta){
  respuesta(Ruta);
});
```

Comment: Gracias. Me ayudo bastante a resolver mi problema!